How to create a parallel program that reads different data
I'm trying to create a process that listens to three COM ports and process the data in parallel. The problem is that I have a machine that sends an ID and proceeds to do a test in one of the COM ports, when this one is finished, it goes to another test and other id number enter to do the first test. How can I deal with this kind of situation?
Machine sends ID -
First test -
Machine send ID (second test) -| Machine sends different id (first test) -
Second test -| First test -
I've tried to use asyncio, aioserial for the com ports.
Here's the code so far.
async def read_motor_id(self, motor_serial=1):
    motor_id = None
    while motor_id == None:
        # id_data = await motor_serial.read_until_async(b'\n')
        # motor_id = id_data.decode().strip()
        motor_id = input("Digite o ID do motor: ")
        if motor_id:
            print(f"Motor ID: {motor_id}")
            await self.queue.put(motor_id)
# I had to put the class cause stack couldn't let me put at the top sorry
Class MotorTest()
def __init__(self):
    self.tasks = []
    self.queue = asyncio.Queue()

async def process_queue(self, oil_serial = 1, water_serial = 1):
    while True:    
        motor_id = await self.queue.get()
        await self.process_motor_id(motor_id, oil_serial, water_serial)
        

async def process_motor_id(self, motor_id, oil_serial = 1, water_serial = 1):
    motor_type = motor_id[-2:]  # OL ou AG
    if motor_type == "OL":
        self.tasks.append(motor_id[:-2])
        await self.test_oil(motor_id, oil_serial)
    elif motor_type == "AG":
        if motor_id[:-2] in self.tasks:
            await self.test_water(motor_id, water_serial)
            
            self.tasks.remove(motor_id[:-2])
        else:
            print(f"Tarefa para motor {motor_id} não encontrada")
    await self.read_motor_id()
    
async def test_oil(self, motor_id, oil_serial =1):
    print(f"Iniciando teste de óleo para motor {motor_id}")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)  # Simulação do teste
    print(f"Finalizando teste de óleo para motor {motor_id}")
    # await oil_serial.read_async_until(aioserial.LF)

async def test_water(self, motor_id, water_serial =1):
    print(f"Iniciando teste de água para motor {motor_id}")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)  # Simulação do teste
    print(f"Finalizando teste de água para motor {motor_id}")
    # await water_serial.read_async_until(aioserial.LF)

async def main()
# motor_serial = aioserial.AioSerial(port='COM1', baudrate=9600)
# oil_serial = aioserial.AioSerial(port='COM2', baudrate=9600)
# water_serial = aioserial.AioSerial(port='COM3', baudrate=9600)

motor_test = MotorTest()

async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
    tg.create_task(motor_test.read_motor_id())
    tg.create_task(motor_test.process_queue())



if __name__ == "__main__":
asyncio.run(main())

`
Reading the docs I think i got a provisory solution, here's the code for it:
class MotorTest:
def __init__(self):
    self.tasks = []
    self.queue = asyncio.Queue()

async def read_motor_id(self, motor_serial=1):
    motor_id = None
    while motor_id == None:
        # id_data = await motor_serial.read_until_async(b'\n')
        # motor_id = id_data.decode().strip()
        motor_id = input("Digite o ID do motor: ")
        if motor_id:
            print(f"Motor ID: {motor_id}")
            await self.queue.put(motor_id)

async def process_queue(self, oil_serial = 1, water_serial = 1):
    while True:    
        motor_id = await self.queue.get()
        asyncio.create_task(self.process_motor_id(motor_id, oil_serial, water_serial))

        

async def process_motor_id(self, motor_id, oil_serial = 1, water_serial = 1):
    motor_type = motor_id[-2:]  # OL ou AG
    motor_clean = motor_id[:-2]
    if motor_type == "OL":
            if  motor_clean not in self.tasks : self.tasks.append(motor_clean)
            asyncio.create_task(self.test_oil(motor_id, oil_serial))
    elif motor_type == "AG":
            if motor_id[:-2] in self.tasks:
                asyncio.create_task(self.test_water(motor_id, water_serial))
            else:
                print(f"Tarefa para motor {motor_id} não encontrada")
                
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.read_motor_id(), asyncio.get_event_loop())
async def test_oil(self, motor_id, oil_serial =1):
    print(f"Iniciando teste de óleo para motor {motor_id}")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)  # Simulação do teste
    print(f"Finalizando teste de óleo para motor {motor_id}")
    # await oil_serial.read_async_until(aioserial.LF)
async def test_water(self, motor_id, water_serial =1):
    print(f"Iniciando teste de água para motor {motor_id}")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)  # Simulação do teste
    print(f"Finalizando teste de água para motor {motor_id}")
    # await water_serial.read_async_until(aioserial.LF)

async def main():
    # motor_serial = aioserial.AioSerial(port='COM1', baudrate=9600)
    # oil_serial = aioserial.AioSerial(port='COM2', baudrate=9600)
    # water_serial = aioserial.AioSerial(port='COM3', baudrate=9600)
    motor_test = MotorTest() 
    async with  asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        tg.create_task(motor_test.read_motor_id())
        tg.create_task(motor_test.process_queue())

asyncio.run(main())

´

Please clarify the question.  You say you want to write a parallel program but you describe a sequential process.  "when this one is finished, it goes to another test" means that one test must finish before the next one starts.

Why do you think you need to "process the data in parallel"? Does your system have enough processing cores to perform actual "parallel programs"?

Its a line of production, one motor have to go for each test but when one motor it's finishing the second test I have another on the first test, so I need make the system that can listens to every motor and direct them to the corresponding test. If the motor already did the first test I need to receive the second if not receive the first one.

Please, fix the indenting for your code-  your code is not really inteliggible, with an unindent inside an if block which could be in any of 3 levels.
Hint: paste the code as is from your code editor, and either quote it with tripple backticks here, or select all, and then click the "format as code" button. Do not attempt to indent lines individually.
